# .NET MAUI & Xamarin Forms: How do I improve Image Source Binding performance and which data is important to store in my DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, xaml, xamarin.forms, maui

I'm currently creating a dating app project using .netmaui for android and iOs.

The Profile.cs file holds all the data for the user and is going to be connected to a DB in the future. For now a testing implementation with local info is created in the contractor.

Profile.cs:

```
  public class Profile : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    List<Image> images = new List<Image>();
    public List<Image> Images
    {
        get { return images; }
        set { images = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Images)); }
    }
public Profile()
    {
        images.Add(new Image());
        images.Add(new Image());
        images.Add(new Image());
        images.Add(new Image());
        images.Add(new Image());
        images.Add(new Image());
        images[0].Source = "photo1.png";
        images[1].Source = "photo2.png";
        images[2].Source = "photo3.png";
        images[3].Source = "photo4.png";
        images[4].Source = "photo5.png";
        images[5].Source = "photo6.png";
    }
```

The ProfilePage.xaml file is binded through a EditProfilePageViewModel.cs by keeping the ProfilePage.xaml.cs empty with only a constructor that initializes the EditProfilePageViewModel.cs

ProfilePage.xaml: ( six images of the same code on a grid )

```
            <ImageButton
                    x:Name="resultImage"
                    Source="{Binding Profile.Images[0].Source}"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Aspect="AspectFill"
                    Grid.RowSpan="1"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                    Command="{Binding HandleImage}"
                    CommandParameter="0"
                    >
            </ImageButton>
```

EditProfilePageViewModel.cs:

This is just a sample of a method that shows the way I change those Images inside my .xaml by altering the values of the Image.Source of the Profile.cs properties:

```
    void DeleteSelectedImage(int index)
    {
        // In case there was a 'Load Image Icon' 
        if (Profile.NumberOfImages < 6)
        {
            // Hide it 
            Profile.Images[Profile.NumberOfImages].Source = "";
        }

        // Every Image takes the SOurce of the next one. Except of the lasy one.
        for(int i=index; i<Profile.NumberOfImages-1; i++)
        {
            Profile.Images[i].Source = Profile.Images[i+1].Source;
        }
           
        // Reset the 'Load image button Icon' after the last existing image
        Profile.Images[Profile.NumberOfImages-1].Source = "temp_swipe_icon.png";

        // Decrease the number of images
        Profile.NumberOfImages--;
    }
```

At this point, whenever I load my app in the simulator, it takes a couple of seconds to load those images. Also some of the images are kinda buggy with a lot of noice(pixels are pink and black like a broken tv signal).

The Question is: Is this the right way of handling images by altering their imagesource? Considering the fact that all images used in the app will have a standard size and resolution, will I need to store in my future DB anything else than the Image.Source?
How do I make the loading faster?

Comment: I tried to address this in your previous question but you did not respond to the comments.  `Images` should be a `List<string>`, not `List<Image>`.  `Image` is a UI element and creating a bunch of them in memory just to act as a source for your XAML is very wasteful.  That might not be your only problem but is certainly the first thing to address.

Comment: @Jason Sorry for not responding, the response was full of questions so I thought that a new one was necessary. Anyways. 

The problem is that let's say that I have an empty profile and I start my app. 
The Profile.cs will retrieve that data from the server. In that case, I need the images somehow to be stored, no?
Because right now, there are images.png files locally

Comment: How are the profile images returned?  Is it just a remote url, or will you have to download and save them locally?  Regardless, you still need to fix the problem I pointed out already with using `Image` as a data source

Comment: I haven't really figured out the structure of the DB elements. Each Image will have a standard size/resolution and will be displayed in the ProfilePage and in a smaller version in the EditProfilePage. Think something like tinder where each user has a bunch of images in their profile. So I don't exactly know what is the ideal format for the management of those files.

Comment: that doesn't really address my question, not does it seem to be related to the core issue your post is about.  If the image is returned as a url, you can just store the url without downloading the image.  If you need to download the image, you can just store it in the filesystem and save the local path in the db.

Comment: I did the change into a string but the performance stayed the same. Which makes kinda sense since the creation of 6 List elements should not be such a burden.

Comment: Because the user is going to swipe other users as well I think the URL solution suits the app better. Also I think it is related to the question as I ask in terms of performance ofcourse, not just programming architecture

Comment: FIRST: Have you confirmed performance on actual device, without debugger attached? Download to a device that you care about, then run it there `without debugger`. (Or stop debugger, launch it from device home page.) If that is within a factor of 2 of performance on emulator, now you know that your emulator tests are useful.

Comment: SECOND: What size are the files? Maybe make smaller "thumbnails", store as local files, and bind to those. Then if user picks one, show the original file. AFAIK, it shouldn't matter what technique you use to change source, it just matters how long it takes to load the files into memory.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve
1) I will test it on both android and iOs. How do I stop debugger, first time hearing about that. 

2) Some random files I god from my camera roll are around 10-13mb.
Because I am going to use a DB I will certainly need a downsize to a standard size for all of the files so each user will have a constant amount of memory in the DB. That's a thing I really want. 
Because the DB is going to be filled with photos from the camera roll, I want to set the resolution/size on loading of the file.

Comment: By *"stop debugger"* I mean if you run Debug build from VS, then in VS press "Stop Debugging", that will end your app. Then on the device or emulator, start the app using its icon. This will run it on its own, instead of with an attached debugger. ALTERNATIVE: menu `Debug / Start Without Debugging` is another way to run the app without debugger attached. For some code, this helps performance. (But often, there is no noticeable improvement.) This is just a **one time test**, to make sure the performance issue isn't caused by debugger.

Comment: *" I want to set the resolution/size on loading of the file."* - I understand. But right now you load **six large images**. Its not surprising performance is bad. ALL Photo Browsers make **small thumbnails** of images. These might be only 64x64 or similar size. (depends how large you show them in your UI.) Then when user clicks on one, you load full resolution of **only that one image**.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Okay , there is a Release Run on VS instead of the Debug one. Same results tho.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve
Thats what Im struggling to do. Resize my images. I couldn't manage to do it with either of the 2 ways I suggested, So the question is still open. If anyone can help me downsize my images even in the process I would be grateful!

Comment: That feels like a somewhat different question than "image source binding performance". Google `xamarin forms resize image`. And `xamarin forms ffimageloading`. Try various suggestions there. Write some code for resizing images. If you get stuck, **start a new question.** As can be seen by the lengthy back-and-forth in comments above, your current question is too broad to be a good fit to StackOverflow. Focus on resizing an image first.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve already have such a question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72175712/netmaui-lower-the-size-resolution-of-my-images-on-loading
You've answered it also(?). So... 
I'd appreciate an answer and not a comment. Thanks for your help

Comment: You'll need to google `xamarin forms ffimageloading` for help on that.